# How to Share a View Across a Navigation Hierarchy with No Animation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have a simple Navigation View Hierarchy that has 2 views it goes between.  I wanted a customized navigation bar, so I have the default one hidden, and I've implemented a Container View which is shared between the 2 views in the nav hierarchy.

Everything works as I want it to, except when I segue to the lower or higher view the top bar appears slides away and reappears on the new view.  I would like it to appear stationary when I push or pop to other views in the hierarchy.

Is there an easy way to do this?  Or should I delete my custom shared Container View and try to make this work with the Navigation Bar (which I have currently "hidden")?

Comment: It seems like the best way to do what I was trying to do would be to just bite the bullet and learn how to customize the default Navigation Controller (change it's height, and add custom buttons).  However, now I'm going to try to accomplish my app with multiple overlapping container views which I can slide on and off screen, because as long as this doesn't cause some unforeseen new problems, it's an approach I'm already very familiar and will get the look I want.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for a client once. The way we did it was, like you said, make an encompassing view controller that housed a container view. Within this container view, we embedded a `UINavigationController` and would manually pop and push `UIViewController`s to its navigation stack. Of course you want to hide the `UINavigationController`'s nav bar.

It sounds like you sort of implemented this, but instead you just embedded a plain old view controller inside your custom navigation controller, and then segue to another view controller that is also embedded in the custom view controller? Ideally you want one instance of this custom nav controller with an embedded `UINavigationController`. I believe you will have to do all the view controller transitions programmatically.

**Opinion**: Personally, I would recommend *against* doing this. I believe that an app should feel like an extension of the OS it's on. A user should feel it's a part of their phone. Using the native navigation bar also decreases the level of effort a user is required to put forth to understand your app.

I know you're thinking "but it's just a nav bar" but we're talking about the same people that will potentially uninstall an app if it takes longer than 2.5s to load.

Comment: I have a normal `UINavigationController` setup between 2 VCs.  Each VC contains an embedded Container View of the same size which linked to the same VC via embedded segues.  I went down this route, because I didn't know how to customize the size and add buttons to the default nav bar, and so far it works exactly as I want, except I don't want it to reanimate when segueing up and down the nav stack.  As far as aesthetics, the only difference between my container view "quasi-nav bar" and the native nav bar, is it is just a bit smaller in height.

Comment: Where is your code for hiding the navbar located? @PlateReverb

Comment: Inside both View Controller classes

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted a customized navigation bar, so I have the default one hidden

That's your mistake. The way to get a customized navigation bar in a UINavigationController interface is to initialize it with `init(navigationBarClass:toolbarClass:)`. Now the built-in navigation controller is using *your* navigation bar! And from there on, all will be well.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621866-init

Comment: My "customized navigation bar" is actually just a separate View within a View Controller that is shared between the different views of the nav stack via separate embedded Container Views on layer's VC.

Comment: Where should this initialization be located?  Is it possible to initialize a Container View or the View Controller it has an embedded segue connection with as a Navigation Bar?  or would I have to create a custom nav bar some other way?